# Using irregular CSS in a .scss file

Tags: sass, polymer

I have some funky formatting which I am using to override a Polymer component. It's the custom variables mixin. Scss does not like it to compile with. Is it possible to set a chunk that doesn't get compiled the sass way? Similar to jekyll raw html tag.

For example

```
// tag do not compile with sass //

--my-component-custom-mixin: {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
};

// tag finish do not compile with sass //
```

Comment: what is the CSS you want to get?

Comment: Exactly that. Polymer does the rest with that Css markup.

Comment: but that is not valid css. Maybe removing the colon

Comment: Yeah I know, hence the question. Do you know any ways of having a raw tag or something in sass

Comment: @blonfu Unfortunately it needs to be exactly that markup.

Comment: but this syntax is for properties, not selectors

Comment: Its a custom property for document level styling. It sits inside a style tag on the document level. It's just handy having it in the css all in one place instead of in a style tag somewhere in the document.

Comment: It is a type of selector, but for polymer custom property mixin, not traditional Css selector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152443/discussion-between-blonfu-and-rhys).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Sass string interpolation (`#{'...'}`) to escape the CSS mixin:

```
SELECTOR {
  --CSS-VARIABLE-NAME: #{'CSS-VARIABLE-VALUE'};
}
```

Example:

```
my-view1 {
  --my-component-custom-mixin: #{'{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }'};
}
```

[demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/5701139f22b08da33e6f332281494f24)